# Use built-in microphone with AudioKit with headphones connected

Tags: ios, swift, audiokit

I'm trying to change the internal microphone with the connected headphones but I do not change it.

I'm using:

```
try! AudioKit.setInputDevice(inputs[1])
try! mic.setDevice(inputs[1])
```

I have tried inputs 0, 1, and 2 but there is no change.

Comment: Have you tried using the debugger to see what every object in `inputs` is?

Comment: Yes, and I see that 0,1 and 2 are from the internal microphone and 3 for the headphones but when trying to change to one of those values
always use the headphones

Comment: Have you tried setting the inputDevice before starting AudioKit?

Comment: Yes and the problem is only when I have the headphones connected

Comment: Try looking this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52765236/use-built-in-microphone-with-audiokit-with-headphones-connected?noredirect=1#comment92454023_52765236